# passing value to a fadeOut callback function

Tags: jquery

what i'm trying to do is to get a recordset of logos, have to arrays.
1: for the display
2: for the bank

i will display 10 logos
on delay i will replace them. with the next 10 from the bank

```
for (var i=0;i<=10;i+=1){
    $("#footerlogo-"+(i+1)).hide().append(DisplayArr[i]).fadeIn();
}


function ReplaceFooterLogos() {
    var runon = 0;
    var tempholder = "";
    for (var i=0;i<=10;i+=1){
        $("#footerlogo-"+(i+1)+"").fadeOut("fast",function(i){
            BankArr.push(DisplayArr.shift());
            DisplayArr.unshift(BankArr.shift());
            $(this).html(DisplayArr[i]).fadeIn()
        });
    }
    $("#mycarousel").delay(5000,function() { ReplaceFooterLogos() });
}

$("#mycarousel").delay(5000,function() { ReplaceFooterLogos() });
```

ignoe the delay function - i have it!

my question is why my the variable i is undefined? and how do i pass values to a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is why my the variable i is undefined?

I suspect you'll find that it's `DisplayArr[i]` that's undefined. `i` should be `11` when the callbacks run.

When you create a *closure* (which is what your `fadeOut` callback is), it has an *enduring reference* to a variable, not a *copy* of the value of the variable at that point in time. So all of your callbacks will see the same `i` value, which will be its value after the loop is finished (`11`). I'm guessing there's no `DisplayArr[11]`. (More about closures here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

Here's how you can fix it:

```
function ReplaceFooterLogos() {
    var runon = 0;
    var tempholder = "";
    for (var i=0;i<=10;i+=1){
        $("#footerlogo-"+(i+1)+"").fadeOut("fast", createCallback(i));
    }
    $("#mycarousel").delay(5000,function() { ReplaceFooterLogos() });

    function createCallback(index) {
        return function(index){
            BankArr.push(DisplayArr.shift());
            DisplayArr.unshift(BankArr.shift());
            $(this).html(DisplayArr[index]).fadeIn();
        };
    }
}
```

What we do there is use a factory function to build your `fadeOut` callback, using its `index` argument rather than `i`. The callback will close over the `index` argument that was given to `createCallback` for the call that created the callback (so, a different one for each callback), and so it will use the value for that iteration of the loop (`0`...`10` inclusive).

Comment: i have changed the $(this) with the footerlogo selector. but the problem now is the the fadeout is working and the fadein is not